# Naked RSA decryption

Tags: rsa

I'm working with some legacy code that uses naked RSA encryption with variable length packets. I've only found example code on how to handle this when the length of the packet is the correct length for the key, but nothing if, say, the data is shorter.

It's not possible for me to switch the RSA encryption to use a modern padded format.

Any help with HOW to decrypt this data is appreciated.